# asp.net mvc angularjs controller throwing error on registration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I have a simple view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Arbitrary Title";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl">
    <div id="grid" kendo-grid k-options="myCtrl.Options"></div>
</div>
```

with the accompanied controller:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

     /***Debugger throws exception here***/
     angular.module("myApp").controller("MyController", MyController);

     MyController.$inject = ['$scope'];

     function MyController($scope) {
          //for brevity
     }
})();
```

The console throws the exception:

- `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MyController' is not a function, got undefined`
- `http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0/ng/...`

I'm fairly new to angular, but from what I have learned, it looks like i'm not registering the controller correctly? Other controllers in the project i'm working on are registered the same way, so i'm a bit lost.

The `_Layout.cshtml` shared view has the `ng-app="myApp"` set as well.